# The origins of なんだ as in 飲まなんだ　or せなんだ

Tags: etymology, classical-japanese, kansai-ben

Even here in Osaka I don't hear it very often among anyone even remotely young, but where does this come from originally? Does anyone have a reference on hand?

If I myself had to guess from what I know of classical Japanese I would think it could be

（打ち消し）ぬ　→　（連用形）に　+　あり　+　たり　→　にありたり　→　にありた　→　なりた　→　なんだ

Thanks.

Comment: Martin doesn't give an etymology, but he lists なんだ→なかった, なんだら→なかったら, なんだり→なかったり, and he adds early Meiji literary usages なんだれ(ど) and んだら→なんだら.

Answer (score 2):

According to a dictionary,

> この語の成立については未詳。一説に「ぬあった」の転かともいう

[source](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0)

Comment: Figured as much; I've never been able to find anything definitive. I'll leave this open a bit longer and then hand the answer your way if nobody else can dig anything up.